# Windows batch - Print last column

Tags: windows, batch-file, csv

In Unix I use this to print the last column of a delimited string:

```
echo "a,b,c,d" | awk -F, '{print $NF}'
```

I have a command that will output a comma delimited string but won't always have the same number of columns.  The command is executed within a loop and each iteration could give a different number of columns.  What can I use to print the last column of this variable-column output?

Comment: Is the number of columns limited somehow (min./max.)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Arbitrary number of columns, doesn't output `!` characters

  ```
  @echo off
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  for /f "delims=" %%L in ('csv command') do (
      set "line=%%L" & set line="!line:,=" "!"
      for %%C in (!line!) do set last_col=%%C
      echo !last_col:~1,-1!
  )
  pause
  ```
- Arbitrary number of columns, outputs `!` characters, but won't integrate inside a bigger loop that relies on `setlocal`.

  ```
  @echo off
  for /f "delims=" %%L in ('csv command') do (
      set "line=%%L"
      setlocal enableDelayedExpansion & set line="!line:,=" "!"
      for %%C in (!line!) do endlocal & set "last_col=%%C"
      setlocal enableDelayedExpansion & echo !last_col:~1,-1!
      endlocal
  )
  pause
  ```

Comment: Thanks!  Both of these options worked for my test.  I'm torn though between using delayed expansion or not.  Attribute that to my lack of knowledge about DE but it seems it has this ! character requirement and I'm not sure of any other side effects.  It seems "safer" to not use it at all?  Or am I just paranoid??

Comment: The delayed expansion mode isn't something weird (not more than the batch syntax itself), it's actually enables normal behavior of variables similar to other languages.

Comment: Thanks.  I ended up using your 2nd option since it uses less %% variables and wasn't clobbering other %% variables used in my other for loops.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a variant without relying on `EnableDelayedExpansion`, provided that the output of the comma-separated-values (CSV) string is stored in `%CSVSTRING%`, and that none of the input values are empty:

```
@echo off 

echo.%CSVSTRING%

rem initialise variables
set LASTCOLUMN=
set /A COUNTER=0

:LOOPBEGIN
rem there is a simple `goto` loop to prevent delayed expansion
set /A COUNTER+=1

for /F "tokens=%COUNTER% delims=," %%A in ("%CSVSTRING%") do (
if "%%A"=="" goto :LOOPEND
set LASTCOLUMN=%%A
goto :LOOPBEGIN)

:LOOPEND
echo.%LASTCOLUMN%
```

Regard that the number of CSV tokens is limited to 31 (per line) due to the `for` command!

---

To get the CSV string stored in the variable `%CSVSTRING%`, there are the following methods (example command `echo a,b,c,d` is used here):

1. redirecting the CSV output to a temporary file:

   ```
   rem store CSV string to temporary file
   (echo a,b,c,d) > list.tmp
   rem load temporary file into variable
   set /P CSVSTRING= < list.tmp
   rem delete temporary file (remove `/P` to avoid prompt)
   del /P list.tmp

   rem notice that `(echo a,b,c,d) | set /P CSVSTRING=` will not work!
   ```
2. embedding the command that returns the CSV output into a `for` command:

   ```
   rem command returning the CSV string is embedded in `for` command
   for /F "delims=" %%A in ('echo a^,b^,c^,d') do set CSVSTRING=%%A
   rem all the `,` must be escaped with `^` here in this sample,
   rem otherwise they will be repaced by spaces
   ```
3. piping the CSV output to the batch script from the top of this answer (let's call it `seeklast.bat`):

   - the command must be given like this:

     ```
     (echo a,b,c,d) | seeklast.bat
     ```
   - the batch script searching for the last CSV token (`seeklast.bat`) must start with this:

     ```
     rem pipe output of command returning CSV string into the batch
     set /P CSVSTRING=
     ```

If you want to provide the CSV string as a command line argument to the above batch script (`seeklast.bat`), it must start with this:

```
    set CSVSTRING=%*
```

Comment: This worked as well!  Very nice and it's good to have an option that does not use delayed expansion.  Wish I could accept two answers!!

Comment: Great! ...but you could upvote every helpful answer, and accept the one that helped you most... ;-)